# Environment with first paragraph in bold and no pagebreaks

Tags: formatting, environments, page-breaking

I would like to setup a new environment which typesets the first paragraph in boldface, the following paragraphs in normal text, and with (possibly) no pagebreaks between the first paragraph and the remaining text. How can I do?

For example, something like the following:

```
\begin{question_and_answer}
This is a question, which should be highlited in bold 
(or by changing font, or by another method) and preceded by a progressive number.

This is the answer, in normal font.

The answer is composed by one or more paragraph. There shouldn't be a 
pagebreak between the first paragraph and the second.
\end{question_and_answer}
```

Or maybe something like this:

```
\begin{question}
This is the question, as the previous example
\end{question}
% no pagebreak here
\begin{answer}
This is the answer, as the previous example
\end{answer}
```

Comment: Do you want a special formation of all paragraphs? Normally you can put the first paragraph in a `minipage`. The special `minipage` can be defined in the header.

Comment: The first paragraph should have a progressive number, and the text in bold. The following paragraphs are "normal".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your paragraphs have only normal text, you can define

```
\newenvironment{highlightnobreak}
  {\par\bfseries
   \def\par{\widowpenalty=10000 \endgraf\penalty10000 }}
  {\par}
```

Use it like

```
... some text before.

\begin{highlightnobreak}
The first paragraph here will be typeset in bold face.
\end{highlightnobreak}

And this text, which is in the paragraph following the
environment will be in normal type.
```

The highlighted paragraph will never end along with a page and will be always accompanied by at least one line of the following paragraph on a page. A page break can however happen before the second-to-last line of the highlighted paragraph.

More customization is possible. For example, a vertical space after the highlighted paragraph can be inserted modifying the definition into

```
\newenvironment{highlightnobreak}
  {\par\bfseries
   \def\par{\widowpenalty=10000 \endgraf\penalty10000 \medskip}}
  {\par}
```

We can improve it with a progressive number and also a vertical space before it, to match the one after:

```
\newcounter{highlightpar}
\newenvironment{highlightnobreak}
  {\medskip\par
   \def\par{\widowpenalty=10000 \endgraf\penalty10000 \medskip}%
   \stepcounter{highlightpar}\bfseries\thehighligthpar. \ignorespaces}
  {\par}
```

### TeXnical note

It's important that the `\par` that closes the environment does more things than usual: here we order it to set `\widowpenalty` to a no-break-before-the-last-line value, then to finish off the paragraph and to tell TeX no-pagebreak-here.

The relevant items TeX will see are then

> 〈last line of the highlighed paragraph〉
>   〈penalty 10000〉
>   〈`\medskipamount` glue〉
>   〈`\parskip` glue〉
>   〈`\baselineskip` glue〉
>   〈first line of the following paragraph〉

so that, by rule, it will not break pages at any of the glue items, because they are not preceded by nondiscardable items. Only the penalty would be a feasible page break point, but it's "infinitely big" and so TeX won't consider it.

Comment: I would like to insert a \medspace after the highlighted paragraph. If I substitute your definition with \newenvironment{highlightnobreak}
  {\par\bfseries
   \def\par{\widowpenalty=10000 \endgraf\penalty10000 }}
  {\par\medskip} then a page break could be inserted. How can I do?

Comment: (And the various paragraphs could have some math material)

Comment: I would advise you against this kind of highlighting: long parts in boldface are hard to read. Can you add to your question a sample text?

Comment: The first paragraph is always short, one or two lines (it is a "question"). The following paragraphs are the "answer". Anyway, I could change font, instead of using a blodface one, or emphasize the question in another way.

Comment: Will I have some problem, if I put the text following the highlighted paragraph into another block environment?

Comment: @zar Probably yes; please, add some samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\par` locally to reset the font and use `\@par` which resets `\par` to its normal definition. I added the penalties given by egreg as well which should avoid a pagebreak right between the two paragraphs. If you want to have no page break at all in all included paragraphs than you can wrap the whole thing in a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myblock}{%
    \par\bfseries
    \def\par{%
        \widowpenalty=10000
        \@par\normalfont
        \penalty10000
    }%
}{%
    \par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myblock}
    text text text text
    text text text text
    text text text text
    text text text text

    further text further text
    further text further text
    further text further text
    further text further text

    further text further text
    further text further text
    further text further text
    further text further text
\end{myblock}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: How can I insert a little unbreakable space between the first and the second paragraph?

Comment: I considered that, but realized that only the boldfaced paragraph needs to be in the environment, so the redefinition of `\par` can be achieved simply by closing the environment. Therefore the `\widowpenalty` setting will hold only for that paragraph and not through all the environment (it's a minor point, I know, but for other settings it might be important).